# PyCharm console encoding errors

Tags: python, eclipse, encoding, intellij-idea, pycharm

Recently I've migrated from Eclipse (LiClipse) to PyCharm. There is one problem which wasn't with Eclipse at all. Problem in encoding, at least, when trying to print something to console.

I've tried this script in both IDE's and in LiClipse it print's soup but in Pycharm raises error.

ERROR while trying to print soup (html) of facebook:

```
 File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u010d' in position 9078: character maps to <undefined>
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Try changing the IDE encoding , information at https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-output-encoding.html

Comment: The same problem occures after do what you advise me to do... File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u010d' in position 11134: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I've changed encoding to UTF-8 Exactly how it is written on that web.

Comment: Did you restart pycharm after changing the encoding?

Comment: Yes I did restart it

Answer (score 0):

For PyCharm console output it is important to set IDE and project encoding properly (not just file encoding). Search for "File Encodings" in Settings window and set IDE and project encoding to UTF-8 (or other).