# Why does PyCharm show invalid unicode characters?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, pycharm

I want to process a unicode UTF-8 text in PyCharm. The characters in the csv file are saved in Excel 2016 as UTF-8 unicode. However, when i try to write in unicode on the code input area or when i output the result in the console, it gives me invalid characters. Also I am not able to write in unicode characters on PyCharm, How can i fix this?

```
import pandas as pd

data1=pd.read_csv('Feb2018_Payroll.csv',encoding='utf-8')
print(data1)
```

When i copy paste the console output here (below), it looks fine. However, in the console it's invalid characters. What could be the reason and how can i solve it?

```
   ተ.ቁ.      የሠራተኛ ስም       የሰሩበት ቀን         የወር ደሞዝ         የኃላፊነት አበል  
0    1.0      ገ/መድህን     30.0            4000.00          250.0   
1    2.0     በቀለ       30.0            2000.00            NaN   
2    3.0     ሽፈራው      30.0            3000.00            NaN
```

Comment: see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209161/pycharm-console-encoding-errors or this one: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-output-encoding.html

Answer (score 4):

So as for now, PyCharm for Mac uses only 16 bits for the Unicode character code.
So this PyCharm for Mac only shows characters in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). As a result, characters that use more than 16 bits are shown as blanks.

With that being said, there are other Intellij derivatives that already display the full range of Unicode characters (32-bit).  One example is the Android Studio for Mac.

Comment: I am using Windows.

Comment: When is PyCharm for Mac going to show full Unicode characters?

Comment: Kaleab, you are in luck.  The PyCharm I installed on my Windows 10 already displays full range of Unicode.

Comment: Liwen, I don't know when PyCharm for Mac will show full range of Unicode characters.  But I think, given time, eventually every app and devices will show the  full range of Unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: If Hindi Chars are not showing in pycharm go to

**File>Settings>Editor>FileEncoding**

Select UTF-8 Everywhere and at last select with BOM option.

[File Encoding in PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZQ8f.png)

Comment: They are not Hindi, they are Amharic.

Comment: You can try these settings with BOM or without BOM option or Select the encoding which supports.

Comment: is this on a windows?

Comment: @HuifangFeng: Yes for windows. I thinking a similar setting will be there for other platforms too.