# Python unicode internalerror message during testing only

Tags: python, unicode, python-unittest

I have a test that (among other things) reads a json.
When I read this file normally, everything is ok, but if I read it when during python's `Unitest.TestCase`, I get a strange error message:

```
INTERNALERROR>     self.message('testStdErr', name=testName, out=out, flowId=flowId)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\_jb_runner_tools.py", line 117, in message
INTERNALERROR>     _old_service_messages.message(self, messageName, **properties)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\messages.py", line 101, in message
INTERNALERROR>     retry_on_EAGAIN(self.output.write)(self.encode(message))
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pycharm\teamcity\messages.py", line 68, in encode
INTERNALERROR>     value = value.encode(self.encoding)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\envs\myrepo\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
INTERNALERROR>     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
INTERNALERROR> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 524-533: character maps to <undefined>`
```

The traceback doesn't lead anywhere in my code, only in Unittest's, so I'm not even sure what I should be looking for. I already changed reading of the json to utf-8, but I still get this message.
As far as I can tell, apart from this message the test passes correctly.

Why am I getting this? What should I be looking for in my code? I'm not providing examples since I'm not sure where in the code this happens. The traceback doesn't lead anywhere.I'm not even sure it has anything to do with the json, but as I googled this message, this seems to be an option.

EDIT: While debugging, this message happens during/after TestCase call to .tearDown(), i.e., after my code finished running

Thanks

Comment: Possibly similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32209161/pycharm-console-encoding-errors

Comment: Tried setting everything to utf-8, as it should. Still no go.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JosefZ: as I said - as the traceback doesn't lead anywhere in my code, it is difficult to provide a reproducible example in this case. The error happens in the tearDown() stage or after, so this might be an IDE/environment/UnitTest issue. None of which is my code

Comment: Try setting up the test and tearing it down _without_ running your actual test. Does the error occur? Just because your code isn't on the stack doesn't mean that your code and test data are not involved.

Comment: If you can't provide an MRE then simply provide the code you are running. Nobody is going to be able to debug this with only the error message but the `self.message('testStdErr'...` makes me suspicious that your code is doing something usual.

Comment: I see. You are of course right, it is just difficult to understand what triggers it. I'll see if I can reproduce it using a minimal code sample and post it here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a PyCharm issue described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-55463/INTERNALERROR-occurs-running-pytest-UnicodeEncodeError-charmap-codec-cant-encode-characters-in-position-...-character-maps-to).
Go to Settings -> Editor -> General -> Console -> Default Encoding route (choosing UTF-8 as the default) and everything seems to be working as expected!